# Google Places API for restaurant : no answer with maxprice > 0

Tags: json, api, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to use Google Places API to get the restaurants around me regarding some criterias. Everything is fine until i'm adding a "maxprice" logic.

With a price above 0 (Google Places handles 0 to 4) the API returns 0 results. Not really interesting if I want to filter between different types or restaurants menus (cheap / expensive etc..)

Here is my current query with results : 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.86459,2.36867&radius=500&rankby=prominence&types=food|restaurant&keyword=burger&key=YOUR-KEY

No results : 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.86459,2.36867&radius=500&rankby=prominence&minprice=0&maxprice=1&types=food|restaurant&keyword=burger&key=YOUR-KEY

Any idea on how to improve it ?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the results in your first query have price information, so they are excluded by any price filtering at all.

Take a look at the place details responses for the two results in your first query: neither have `price_level` fields (because Google's database lacks this information for these places).  So both `minprice` and `maxprice` filters will exclude these results.